# ruby net_dav sample puts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, webdav, null

I'm trying to put a file on a site with WEB_DAV. (a ruby gem)

When I follow the example, I get a nil exception

```
#### GEMS
require 'rubygems'
begin
  gem "net_dav"
rescue LoadError
  system("gem install net_dav")
  Gem.clear_paths
end
require 'net/dav'


uri = URI('https://staging.web.mysite');
user = "dave"
pasw = "correcthorsebatterystaple"

dav = Net::DAV.new(uri, :curl => false)
dav.verify_server = false
dav.credentials(user, pasw)

cargo = ("testing.txt")
File.open(cargo, "rb") { |stream|
  dav.put(urI.path +'/'+ cargo, stream, File.size(cargo))
}
```

when I run this I get

```
`digest_auth': can't convert nil into String (TypeError)
```

this relates to line 197 in my nav.rb file.

```
 request_digest << ':' << params['nonce']
```

So what I'm wondering is what step did I not add? 
Is there a reasonable example of the correct use of this gem?  Something that does something that works would be sweet :)

*SIDE QUESTION:*    Is this the correct gem to use to do web_DAV?  It seems an old unmaintained gem, perhaps there's something used by more to accomplish the task?

Comment: As for your side question, net_dav is maintained it just isn't released.  `git clone https://github.com/devrandom/net_dav` and `gem build net_dav.gemspec` and `gem install net_dav-0.5.0.gem` to get the latest.

Answer (score 0):

Try referencing the hash with a symbol rather than a string, i.e.

```
request_digest << ':' << params[:nonce]
```

In a simple test

baz = "baz"
   params = {:foo => "bar"}
   baz << ':' << params['foo']

results in the same error as you're getting.